# creating a Symfony 4.4 project on windows using composer 1.10.26 : Script cache:clear returned with error code 255 dotenv

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, php-7.3, symfony-4.4

Since yesterday, I have a problem creating a project with the command: composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:"^4.4" my_project_directory on windows. I used php 7.3 symfony 4.4 composer 1.10.0 or 1.10.26 for I have to train on this development environment I am new to dev on symfony. I tried many things without success, and I don't understand what I did wrong. Thanks in advance for any help

```
Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Exception\PathException: Unable to read the "C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory/.env" environment file. in C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php:514
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(65): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->doLoad(false, Array)
!!  #1 C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php(85): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('C:\\_EnvTest\\my_...')
!!  #2 C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory\config\bootstrap.php(17): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->loadEnv('C:\\_EnvTest\\my_...')
!!  #3 C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory\bin\console(30): require('C:\\_EnvTest\\my_...')
!!  #4 {main}
!!    thrown in C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory\vendor\symfony\dotenv\Dotenv.php on line 514

Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Does the .env file exist in C:\_EnvTest\my_project_directory?

Comment: .env file didn't exist I create an other project with composer 2 and copy .env file but i don't know if it's correct method. When i do php bin/console it seems work.

But on server:start and cache:clear I've got an other error i don't know if it's linked. (Attempted to call an undefined method named "setSchemaIgnoreClasses" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Configuration".)


Does it important when installing a project to have the same composer version use ?